# C++ Class variables not printing the right values assigned

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm trying to create a simple class called 'Game' and assign some values to all three variables. However every time I run it, the values printed at the screen are completely irrelevant, and I'm pretty sure it has to do something with the class constructors but I don't know what exactly.The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Game
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string winner;

public:

    Game();
    Game(int IDvalue, string NAMEvalue );
    ~Game();

    void setId(int IDvalue);
    void setName(string NAMEvalue);
    void setWinner(string WINNERvalue);

    int getId();
    string getName();
    string getWinner();

    void status1();

};

Game::Game()
{
    id = 0;
    name = " ";
    winner = " ";
}

Game::Game(int IDvalue, string NAMEvalue)
{
    IDvalue = id;
    NAMEvalue = name;
    winner = " ";
}

Game::~Game()
{

}

void Game::setId(int IDvalue)
{
    IDvalue = id;
}

void Game::setName(string NAMEvalue)
{
     NAMEvalue = name;
}

void Game::setWinner(string WINNERvalue)
{
    WINNERvalue = winner;
}

int Game::getId()
{
    return id;
}

string Game::getName()
{
    return name;
}

string Game::getWinner()
{
    return winner;
}

void Game::status1()
{
    cout << "Game's id : " << id << endl;
    cout << "Game's type : " << name << endl;
    cout << "Game's winner : " << winner << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Game a(1, "Something");
    a.setWinner("Someone");

    a.status1();

    return 0;
}
```

As you might have noticed (I'm sure you have) I'm pretty new to C++ ,so go easy on me...

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `void Game::setWinner(string WINNERvalue) {WINNERvalue = winner;}` has no (zero, zip, nada) net effect.   The argument is passed by value, and assigned.    The function does not change `winner` and the change of `WINNERvalue` is not seen by the caller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Game::Game(int IDvalue, string NAMEvalue)
{
    IDvalue = id;
    NAMEvalue = name;
    winner = " ";
}
```

Most of these assignments are backwards. To be consistent, the last line should have been

```
" " = winner;
```

This constructor isn't initializing `id` and `name`; instead it's assigning the (garbage) values of `id` and `name` to the parameters `IDvalue` and `NAMEvalue`, which are local variables in the function, so they're destroyed when the constructor returns and no one can see their modified values.

Fix:

```
Game::Game(int IDvalue, string NAMEvalue)
{
    id = IDvalue;
    name = NAMEvalue;
    winner = " ";
}
```

Or better:

```
Game::Game(int IDvalue, string NAMEvalue)
    : id(IDvalue)
    , name(NAMEvalue)
    , winner(" ")
{
}
```

By the way, your setter functions have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the member variables to the parameters instead of vice versa on the second constructor and `set` functions.

```
Game::Game(int IDvalue, string NAMEvalue)
{
    IDvalue = id;       -->      id   = IDvalue;    OR setID(id);
    NAMEvalue = name;   -->      name = NAMEvalue; OR setName(name);
    winner = " ";
}

void Game::setId(int IDvalue)
{
    IDvalue = id;        -->     id = IDvalue;
}


// ... the rest of the set functions
```